# conceptual proof of an inequality

Tags: inequality

Let $0\leq t\leq 1$ be a real number and let $z=1-t\sin^2(x)$. Set also
$$
F(t,x)=z(1-z).
$$
Note that $F(1,x)=\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x)$. Case by case analysis shows that
$$
\max_{t\in [0,1], x\in [0,2\pi]} F(t,x)\leq \max_{x\in [0,2\pi]}F(1,x). 
$$
I wonder if there is a better way to show this instead of case by case analysis. Any idea is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You say inequality, but I can't see an inequality in your post (besides $0\leq t\leq 1$), is this a typo?

Comment: Sure. I will fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For $t\in [0,1]$, note that $1-z=t\sin^2(x)\leq \sin^2(x)$. Therefore, $\max(t\sin^2(x))\leq \max(\sin^2(x))$.

Also note that $z=1-t\sin^2(x)=1-t+t\cos^2(x)$. Therefore $\max(z)=1$ and hence $\max(\cos^2(x))=\max(z)$ and your inequality follows.

Answer (score 0):

First off, notice that writing $a:=\sin^2(x)$, we can rewrite the optimisation problem as $\max_{t \in [0,1],x \in [0,2\pi]} F(t,x)=\max_{t \in [0,1],a \in [0,1]} at(1-at)$.

Then it becomes clear that for any $a,t \in [0,1]$, we can choose $u:=at \in [0,1]$. Defining $G(a,t):=at(1-at)$, we obtain $G(a,t)=G(1,u)$, and your observation follows.